# How to make Jquery easing have an up and down arrow?

Tags: jquery

I want to make Jquery easing have to two arrows (up arrow and down)

(its look in the head of box has circle of contain up arrow and down arrow) . The first, arrow be appear down to becoming box become down and when box down, the arrow become up. The code for this:

but its just for up and down box not appear arrow. I have stack to make it. Please help regarding this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: so you want to change that image on up and down?

Comment: tried to clear up the english but it's very hard to understand.

Comment: "arrow be appear down to becoming box become down and when box down, the arrow become up" -- unable to understand.

Comment: @YadavChetan: yes, of course.

Comment: @Liam: thank you Liam for editing my question and so sorry for my english is bad... Can you help me, how do that?

Comment: you can change src of image using jquery

Comment: @YadavChetan: Could you please to help to code that? thanks

Comment: @Budi ok i will as soon as i reach to my office

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this i am giving here demo , i just change the img src of img tag with id `img1`

i provide you a demo ... try to implement this..

**Script here**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#img1').click(function () {

        if ($("#img1").attr("src")=="up.jpg") {
            $("#img1").attr("src","down.jpg");
            $(".panel-box").slideUp('slow');

        }else if($("#img1").attr("src")=="down.jpg"){
            $("#img1").attr("src","up.jpg");
           $(".panel-box").slideDown('slow');

        }
    });
});       
</script>
```

**HTML code**

```
<img id="img1" src="up.jpg" alt="Click here" width="100px" height="100px"/>
<fieldset> 
<div class="panel-box" > 
<form>        

        <div class="column1">
            <label>Arrival Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="arrival" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
        </div>
        <div class="column2">
            <label>Departure Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="departure" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
        </div>
    <div class="column3">
        <a href="#" class="button" style=" vertical-align:middle; margin-top:18px;">Book Now</a>
    </div>

</form>    
</div>  
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Could you please to make demo on Jsfiddle. Thank you

Comment: can you provide your html code so that i can do it fast

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adrian_tapulaki/QEWtd/ thats html code

Comment: @Budi so you want to show and hide that div with click event right?

Comment: why use alert? Its appear box "0" before close

Comment: @Budi oh i forgot to remove that it just for check

Comment: Why if use mozilla its work perfect but if another browser its must click twice at first? Thank you

Comment: @Budi i am really sorry i mistaken now i changed the code check it

Comment: @Budi hope you got it ... :)